# Automate `select cell` and `evaluate selected cell`

Tags: cells

Manually I can `select` a set of cells (or one grouped cell) and click `evaluate cell`

My questions

Is it possible to start this job from the commandline?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to do this? Do you need the result back in the command line, or do you need the evaluated notebook displayed? Also, did you consider using package files (`.wl`)?

Comment: @LukasLang Thank you your hint `package files .wl` ! Yes I would like to get the result back in the command line. The reason why: I want to avoid building a local function, which contains all these listed cells.

Comment: How about `SelectionMove`, https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SelectionMove.html